# Dialogue of/on issues of global interest

Tags: prepositions, exam-questions

> The president underscored the need for (A) a constructive and a realistic dialogue (B) of issues of global interest.(C)

My book says part *(B)* of sentence is wrong, we don't need to use **a** here, I agree with that but isn't part **(C)** also wrong ? I guess it should be dialogue **ON** issues of global interest. Am I correct ?

Edit : by **a** I am referring to second **a**, the one which is with *realistic*.

Comment: Your book is just making things up. It's entirely a stylistic choice whether to include the article *(**a** dialogue)*. And there's no fixed rule regarding how you might link that element to *issues of global interest* (you could "validly" use ***of, on, about, concerning, regarding,*** etc.).

Comment: Perhaps a moderator deleted because my own comment has been deleted. Why my comment was deleted, did I break any rule of SE ?

Comment: I don't know. I've seen nothing here or on your other recent question that might break any rules. Eventually, most of these comments will probably be deleted, but the mods don't usually bother much about even blatantly Off-Topic comments while a new question is "settling in". My first comment here isn't much of an "answer", but I'd expect it to be left at least until someone posts a more comprehensive response.

Comment: I don't understand the structure of the question.  It's not clear what parts of the sentence (A), (B), and (C) refer to.

Comment: I removed the comments because they were made obsolete when you updated your question. Comments are meant to be temporary, so you did the right thing by updating your question. I may have deleted them too quickly. I'm on my mobile and not quite as effective as I am on a bigger screen.

Comment: @Andrew It's a little confusing to me as well, but the error spotting questions mark the end of the section, not the beginning. 'A' refers to the initial part up to the (A) and 'B' is the part from (A) to (B).

Answer (score 1):

"A constructive dialogue of those issues" certainly is unusual.

My preferred preposition to introduce the subject of a dialogue is "about", by a wide margin. However, I see by [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dialogue%20on%2Cdialogue%20about%2Cdialogue%20concerning&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdialogue%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdialogue%20about%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdialogue%20concerning%3B%2Cc0) that it's less common than "on". The participle "concerning" could work too, but is significantly less common. I don't think any of them would raise any eyebrows, though.

[image: dialogue]

Note that in the use of "dialogue" as a verb (business jargon, not universally accepted), "about" is the only natural follow-up. This is probably because it appears to be an [excrescent](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/excrescent#Adjective) synonym for "talk".

> We need to dialogue about your use of resources.

Comment: I wasn't talking about the 'of' which is preceding interest. I know 'of global interest' is correct but I was concerned about the 'of' which is preceding 'issues' . I guess you didn't read question properly.

Comment: @user212388 My mistake. Edited the answer to address that one instead.